# How to align two texts from different rows in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, alignment, row, android-jetpack-compose

I have 3 texts in one row and then another three in another row inside a LazyColumn

[image]

I want to align the "text" in the center of the first row with "15.025" value in the second row

I've used

```
TextAlign.Center
```

on both of the Texts and

```
             horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
             verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
```

set this on the Row but it doesn't work. Any tips please?

I'm pretty new in Compose, sorry for the basic question.

Comment: Could you show the code regarding these composables (Rows, Texts, LazyColumn)?

Answer (score 9):

You can use `Modifier.weight` to make the width of "left view" equals to the width of "right view". It will make the middle text on each row always center.

```
Row(Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
    Text(
        text = "Start",
        modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
    )
    Text(
        text = "Center",
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center, // you can also fixed the width of center text
    )
    Text(
        text = "End",
        modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
        textAlign = TextAlign.End
    )
}
```

If your text content is always short, you can also use `Box` to make the middle text always center.

```
Box(Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
    Text(text = "Start", modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterStart))
    Text(text = "Center", modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center))
    Text(text = "End", modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterEnd))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, this does center it as I've asked but I can't get the Box code working. My text content is always short as you've mentioned. However I think I've poorly described what I want. I managed to get it to work how I want using your help, I'm gonna post the result and what I've used.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I wanted to achieve and with the help of @Linh I did

[image]

Here's how I did it.

```
Column(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    Row(Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
        Text(
            text = "Start",
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1.5f),
            textAlign = TextAlign.Start
        )
        Text(
            text = "Center",
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
            textAlign = TextAlign.Start
        )
        Text(
            text = "End",
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
            textAlign = TextAlign.End
        )
    }
}
```

Thanks again for the help.